# Visually indicate that filter has been set in extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is there a way to visually indicate that a filter has been set in extjs (4.2) grid?

Per default the header text becomes itallic. But i am using the ext-theme-gray look and feel and the visual indication is hard to see.

I would like to set an icon on the header, or even darken the header text. Even adding some text to the toolbar would suffice.

Comment: why am i getting negative votes for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to visually change the column header when setting a filter on a column.

Make sure you include the GridFilters.css.

eg :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lib/ext-4.2.1.883/ux/grid/css/GridFilters.css" />
```

Then inside the CSS file you can change style values. Per default you see this :

```
.ux-filtered-column {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #56b8ff;
}
```

You can change the color or even add an icon.

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When a **Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter** is marked as *active*, the 'activate' event is launched and at some moment **Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature.updateColumnHeadings()** method is called.

This is the method that sets the "ux-filtered-column" css class on the column header by default(default config for **Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature.filterCls**).

You may change this FiltersFeature property or overwrite the method to do something else.